# Invoking KeyPress Event Without Actually Pressing Key

Tags: javascript, keypress

Just wondering. Is it possible to invoke a key press event in JavaScript without ACTUALLY pressing the key ? For example lets say, I have a button on my webpage and when that button is clicked I want to invoke a event as if a particular key has been pressed. I know it weird but can this be done in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be done using [initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initKeyEvent). It's a little verbose to use, though. If that bothers you, use jQuery, as shown in [@WojtekT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514164/851498)'s answer.

Otherwise, in vanilla javascript, this is how it works:

```
// Create the event
var evt = document.createEvent( 'KeyboardEvent' );

// Init the options
evt.initKeyEvent(
             "keypress",        //  the kind of event
              true,             //  boolean "can it bubble?"
              true,             //  boolean "can it be cancelled?"
              null,             //  specifies the view context (usually window or null)
              false,            //  boolean "Ctrl key?"
              false,            //  boolean "Alt key?"
              false,            //  Boolean "Shift key?"
              false,            //  Boolean "Meta key?"
               9,               //  the keyCode
               0);              //  the charCode

// Dispatch the event on the element
el.dispatchEvent( evt );
```

Comment: what is the "el" (double code not included) in your code ?

Comment: In typescript I had to do: `const evt = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { shiftKey: true, etc... });`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jquery:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; //key code
$("#some_element").trigger(e);
```

Comment: so for example if I have a button as `<input type='button' onclick='DisplayKeyCode()'>`, what needs to be included in the function `DisplayKeyCode()` so as it alerts the key code (50 in this case)

Comment: Instead of using "onclick" use onkeydown="DisplayKeyCode(event)" and alert event.keyCode.

Comment: what is `event.keyCode` in this case ? I mean do I have to define `keyCode` anywhere ?

Comment: No, it is an event object passed by the browser. "event.keyCode" is a code of a key that you pressed.

Comment: Sorry But it doesn't work. I tried this - 
`function DisplayCode(event){`
`var event = jQuery.Event("keydown");`
`event.which = 50;`
`alert(event.keyCode);`
`}`
and html as
`<input type="text" onkeydown="DisplayCode(event);">`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11055/discussion-between-wojtekt-and-sachyn)