# javascript dispatchEvent Keypress, returns true , but input field is still empty

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I need to trigger or say dispatchEvent KeyPress inside an Input box,
I have tried a lot with "**initKeyboardEvent**" , "**initKeyEvent**" , "**createEvent**", even I found similar question's answers but nothing seems to work, neither in firefox, nor in chrome (I think they may be deprecated), as
**KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent()**, is deprecated.

like we have

```
document.getElemntByID('button').click();
```

I want to do something like:

```
document.getElemntById('email').keyPress(charCode('a'));
```

but unfortunately I am not able to make keypress work in any way.

I know it is possible in jQuery , but I want to do it in pure javascript, after all jquery uses Javascript in backend , so there must be a way , if I am not wrong.

====Update=========
I wonder

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown(), true);

function keyDown(){
alert('keydown');
}

var fireOnThis = document.getElementById('pwph');
if( window.KeyEvent ) {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('KeyEvents');
    evObj.initKeyEvent( 'keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 72, 0 );
} else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    evObj.initUIEvent( 'keydown', true, true, window, 1 );
  evObj.keyCode = 72;
}
fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

This code returns me true , and even the eventListner is catching this event, then why am I not able to see any text inside the input box?
====================update============================
This seems to work for everyone, but why does it leaves my text field empty, even after returning true?

```
// Create the event
var evt = document.createEvent( 'KeyboardEvent' );

// Init the options
evt.initKeyEvent(
             "keypress",        //  the kind of event
              true,             //  boolean "can it bubble?"
              true,             //  boolean "can it be cancelled?"
              null,             //  specifies the view context (usually window or null)
              false,            //  boolean "Ctrl key?"
              false,            //  boolean "Alt key?"
              false,            //  Boolean "Shift key?"
              false,            //  Boolean "Meta key?"
               9,               //  the keyCode
               0);              //  the charCode

// Dispatch the event on the element
el.dispatchEvent( evt );
```

Comment: `charCode('a')` will invoke the function... You need to pass function expression...

Comment: How about adding the `onkeydown` event to the DOM Element? Like: `<input type="text" onkeydown="function()">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking KeyPress Event Without Actually Pressing Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514123/invoking-keypress-event-without-actually-pressing-key)

Comment: Input element is not my hand :)

Comment: @Boratzan yea may be but that code does not work for me, I wonder why..returns me true but nothing happens to the input field ,it is still empty

Comment: 9 is the keyCode for tabulation, right?

Comment: yea right, this is just an example, 72 which is a keycode for "h" does not work either, also if there is some text already in the input field , backspace keycode 8 also does not work. in whole no keyboard event firing on input field.

Comment: you can check the same code above with any website which have an input field, just change the id, on which you'll dispatch the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to dispatch a keyPress event inside an Input element to pass the data-bind condition(KnockOut js) event , but unfortunately KeyPress didn't worked for me, Instead I used change event in place of it.

so I did this:

```
element = document.getElementById('idTxtBx_SAOTCS_ProofConfirmation');

    element.value = '8885';   // this alone was not working as keypress.

    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true); // adding this created a magic and passes it as if keypressed
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

so **.value** and **change** event together made, fake inputText or keypressed event successful.

Answer (score 0):

i think so like you want to add event listener on input box

```
           var element = document.getElementById("email");

            document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
                console.log("keypresh")

            })
            var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
            evt.initEvent("keypress", false, true);
            // adding this created a magic and passes it as if keypressed
            element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: addEventListner is something which Listens when an event is fired,I don't want to Listen , I want to Fire or dispatch an event (keypress), on an Input field.

Comment: I have gone through this Link already, Mouse events works but not keyboard events:
var keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key : "a", char : "a", shiftKey: true});
    
    document.getElementById('email').dispatchEvent(keyEvent);

returns true , but does not enter any character in the input box whose ID is given.

Answer (score 0):

initEvent is deprecated or about to be removed. Instead, you can use it like this:

```
element = document.getElementById('idTxtBx_SAOTCS_ProofConfirmation');
element.value = '8885';   // this alone was not working as keypress.

const evt = new Event("change", {
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
});

element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```